# Directive selector doesn't find element

Tags: typescript, angular

When I change the selector to `'input'` it works on every input it can find. If I change it to `'input[numeric]'` nothing happens (yes the `input[numeric]` is really there).
What am I doing wrong? Isn't it supposed to work like this? It says CSS selector in the documentation...

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
    selector: 'input[numeric]',
    host: {
        '(input)' : 'onInputChange()'
    }
})
export class NumberFormatDirective {

    constructor(public model: NgModel, public element: ElementRef) {
        console.log(1);
    }

    onInputChange(): any {
        console.log(2);
    }
}
```

The template looks like this:

```
<input *ngIf='!isMultiLine()'
       [attr.readonly]='readonly'
       [attr.disabled]='isInputDisabled()'
       [attr.minlength]='minLength'
       [attr.maxlength]='maxLength'
       [attr.numeric]='isNumeric()'
       [(ngModel)]='value' (ngModelChange)='valueChanged($event)'
       (keyup.enter)='updateValueRestore()'
       (keyup.escape)='resetValue()'
       (focus)='onFocus()'
       (blur)='onBlur()'
       autocomplete='off'/>
```

Comment: How does the `input[numeric]` that "is really there" look like exactly?

Comment: I added the html code

Comment: I think it should work. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Its working as expected.

Comment: I added the template code. Maybe you could take a look at it too. Can't the element by found because the attribute is added dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Check

plnkr.co/edit/VFRqjipiFFJqYdnSIM49?p=preview

Its working as expected.

Comment: The answer should contain the essential part directly instead of just linking to an external resource. Links can become stale.